# Is there something like SharedPreferences in Blackberry as in Android?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I want to implement a SharedPreferences kind of thing in my BlackBerry application similar to what is available in Android. What i want to do is store the login details after authenticating them so that the user is not required to login again and again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [PersistentStore](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/PersistentStore.html) class from RIM SDK to store data and share it among different applications when necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You can use both PersistenStore and RuntimeStore to save data over the BB device. The main difference is that the persistent store will save your data even after a phone reset. But the runtime store will erase them after resetting the device. You can use the one that you see better for usage